# Why does java.util.scanner repeat loop for every space

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I had a simple question. I've been exploring basic input validation in java (Only accept integers or doubles etc.. from user). The code below Works great for simple applications but it did spark my curiosity; whenever you input a letter then follow it with a space then another letter, it displays the "Try again. Input numbers only " message twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input Number, BOi");
        //Basic input validation. Only Accepts Integers.
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
            sc.next();//This Clears the Scanner for next input
            System.out.println("Try again. Input numbers only.");
        }
        int userInput = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("CONGRATS! YOU'VE ENTERED THE NUMBER: " + 
userInput);
    }
}
```

If I were to input 
        `p p p`
then the result would be

```
Try again. Input numbers only.
Try again. Input numbers only.
Try again. Input numbers only.
```

I would expect the result to just be `Try again. Input numbers only.` displayed once. Can anybody explain why this happens? I've heard the term "regex" thrown around but don't know if it's relevant. Thank you!

Comment: That is because scanner Next() tokenizes the line into an array of strings (each p is a different token) use nextline() instead to clear for the next try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `next()` does not consume the whole line. It only consumes the first word until space and the remaining words stays.

Thus when your loop will repeat as many words you have until it finds an `int`.
For example here you are giving `P P P` means 3 words hence thrice iteration

Thus you should use:

- `sc.nextLine()` if you are expecting non integer and parse it
- `sc.nextInt();` and handle exception if someone inputs anything other
  than `int`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a lack of knowledge of how  `Scanner` really works.

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So when you enter `p p p`, `Scanner.nextInt()` will split `p p p` into `p` then `p` and then `p`. Thats why you get 3 times the same message.

Use `nextLine()` method to get the whole line and not "skip" any whitespace.